# Siunitx table one number aligned incorrectly

Tags: tables, tabularx, siunitx

Edit: Fixed it by replacing the incorrect row with another row and changing the numbers according to the incorrect row.

% Former Question

I created a table with siunitx. There is one number which is aligned incorrectly (Siunitx version 3.0.28).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, captions=tableheading, titlepage,bibliography=totocnumbered]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
% Sprache und Schriftart

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

% Einheiten
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}

% Tabelle
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}

% Darstellung Standardabweichung
\newcommand{\st}[1]{{(}#1{)}}

% Darstellung Signifikanz
\newcommand{\sig}[1]{\textsuperscript{\emph{#1}}}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Häufigkeit}
    \label{tab:Haufigkeit}
    \sisetup{
  input-symbols         = (),
  table-format          = 1.2,
  table-space-text-post = \textsuperscript{\emph{a}},
  table-space-text-pre  = ~,
  table-align-text-post = false,
  table-align-text-pre  = false,
  table-auto-round} 

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X*{4}S}
    \toprule
    & {Gegner (1)} & {Neutrale (2)} & {Befürworter (3)} & {Gesamt} \\
    \midrule
    
    Option 1 & 3,22\sig{a} & 3,02 \sig{b} & 2,78\sig{c} & 3,0 \\
        & \st{1,173} & \st{1,225} & \st{1,173} & \st{1,206} \\
    
    Option 2 & 3,32\sig{a} & 2,82\sig{b} & 2,64\sig{b} & 2,9 \\
        & \st{1,38} & \st{1,458} & \st{1,385} & \st{1,439} \\
    
    Option 3 & 3,93\sig{a} & 3,82\sig{a} & 3,38\sig{b} & 3,71 \\
        & \st{1,136} & \st{1,158} & \st{1,226} & \st{1,194} \\
        
    Option 4 & 4,25\sig{a} & 4,01\sig{b} & 3,45\sig{c} & 3,9 \\
        & {(}1,352{)} & \st{1,51} & \st{1,558} & \st{1,517} \\

    \bottomrule

    \end{tabularx}
    
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Alignment error]

Is there any idea how to fix this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: It works fine for me, with LuaLaTeX over TL2020. There are overfull warnings but the rounding and alignment are fine.

Comment: When I run your code on my system (MacTeX2021, w/ all updates applied: LuaHBTeX, Version 1.13.2, LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1, siunitx 2021-08-27 v3.0.28), I get `1.16`, not `1.158`, and the number is aligned on the decimal marker, as it should be. Please tell us which version of `siunitx` you're employing.

Comment: Where can I see the version I use?

Comment: Can you open the log file and search for "siunitx"?

Comment: I tried that with no result. My logfile starts with: "This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Tabellenversuche.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-03-06> (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrartcl.cls
Document Class: scrartcl 2020/01/24 v3.29 KOMA-Script document class (article)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/"; is that right? This is all I get for siunitx: "/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx.sty".

Comment: @Karl - What's in the line immediately below "(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx.sty"?

Comment: The easiest way to get a list of package versions is to add `\listfiles` to the input, then you will get a `File list` toward the end of the log. As others have observed, this looks very much like a version issue, as I don't see it with  v2.8e or with v3.0.28. Moreover, I can't think of a bug in this area in v2 in recent years, and it seems unlikely you are using v3.

Comment: I use version  2.8b.
"(siunitx.sty    2020/02/25 v2.8b A comprehensive (SI) units package)"

Comment: I updated siunitx to v3.0.28. There is no rounding error anymore. Yet, the bracket is incorrectly aligned.

Comment: I don't see this with _exactly_ the same set up. Could you send me your input and log files?

Comment: Yes, of course! Would you mind telling me how I can send you the files? Thank you very much for your quick respose and help.

Comment: joseph.wright@morningstar2.co.uk